# Using values of attributes as filters in XML python

Tags: python, xml, attributes

I have the xml file below and

```
data_string = """
<Bookstore>
   <Book ISBN="ISBN-13:978-1599620787" Price="15.23" Weight="1.5">
      <Title>New York Deco</Title>
      <Authors>
         <Author Residence="New York City">
            <First_Name>Richard</First_Name>
            <Last_Name>Berenholtz</Last_Name>
         </Author>
      </Authors>
   </Book>
   <Book ISBN="ISBN-13:978-1579128562" Price="15.80">
      <Remark>
      Five Hundred Buildings of New York and over one million other books are available for Amazon Kindle.
      </Remark>
      <Title>Five Hundred Buildings of New York</Title>
      <Authors>
         <Author Residence="Beijing">
            <First_Name>Bill</First_Name>
            <Last_Name>Harris</Last_Name>
         </Author>
         <Author Residence="New York City">
            <First_Name>Jorg</First_Name>
            <Last_Name>Brockmann</Last_Name>
         </Author>
      </Authors>
   </Book>
</Bookstore>
"""
```

I have an sample code on "Find the first name of the author of a book that weighs 1.5 oz"

```
root.find('Book[@Weight="1.5"]/Authors/Author/First_Name').text
```

And this works fine.

I then tried to extract the last_name by filtering 
by using the code below

```
root.find('Author[@Residence="New York City"]/Last_Name').text
```

It gave me an error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

How can I solve this? And why this is wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the query should be :

```
root.find('Book/Authors/Author[@Residence="New York City"]/Last_Name').text
```

because you start the search from the root, and you are only able to see the direct children of root `Bookstore`, which are the `Book` tags.

Note that as you have many authors living in NewYork, you may need to find them all :

```
names = [tag.text for tag in root.findall('Book/Authors/Author[@Residence="New York City"]/Last_Name')]

print(names)
>>>['Berenholtz', 'Brockmann']
```

Here `findall` returns a list containing the authors lastnames tags, you can iterate on and apply the `text` attribute

Comment: Okay. Got it. Thank you for the advice too! it make sense.